В windows 2019 слетают вручную заданный ip адрес после troubleshooting
На VMware поставил виртуалку Windows Server 2019 (network adapter NAT), в свойствах сетевого адаптера устанавливаю вручную ip адрес и маску. Типа 10.8.0.15, gateway 10.8.0.1, маска 255.255.255.0. После сохранения пишет Undefinded network и доступа к интернету соответственно нет. Если решать через troubleshooting, то он пишет "Ethernet doesn’t have a valid IP configuration" и, конечно, все чинит, и интернет начинает работать, но при этом ip адреса в свойствах сетевого адаптера слетают и назначаются автоматом dhpc.
Переустанавливал драйвер, делал все обновления, ресетил конфиги ipconfig /renew и т.п., убирал ipv6, добавлял вручную dns 8.8.8.8, additional 8.8.4.4, отключал Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter, пытался перезапустить dhcp клиент, ничего не помогает. Я только учусь, поэтому, наверное, многого не понимаю, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

какая проблема если все чинит, и интернет начинает работать

Такая, что “ но при этом ip адреса в свойствах сетевого адаптера слетают и назначаются автоматом dhpc.”. Мне нужно чтобы работало при назначенном вручную IP
